# display second line graph over the first (jfreechart)

Tags: java, jfreechart

By default the second line graph is under the first.
I ask if it's possible to display the second line graph over the first.
Note that in code I first render the first line and after the second line.

This is ok for very different dataset but I'm working on very "close" dataset and looks like the second line graph not appearing (in some ranges)

example:on range x [1.5,3.0] the first line is over the second

[image: on range x [1.5,3.0] the first line is over the second]

Hope for your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt That was really fast response. You are right! Thanks a lot! Sorry for duplicate. Should I mark my question as duplicate or comment the solution or something?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt
`XYPlot plot = jFreeChart.getXYPlot();

plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);` 

Works, thanks!

Comment: I'd just wait. I don't think you can mark the question as a duplicate yourself but when other reviewers see your comment they will probably agree that it's a duplicate and this will resolve itself.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Actually the only different is that I refer to line graphs and not to bars. I don't know if my question help others to find what they want (lines overlapping, not bars). We'll see!
Thanks again anyway!